# Push message preview show and hide iOS

Tags: ios, push, preview

I have implemented pubnub chat in my application and iOS push message for every chat message. So if user A send 20 messages to user B then user B see 20 messages in his iPhone lockscreen. I want to group all 20 push messages into 1 message showing the app name and messages count on iPhone lock screen. Many application implement it like viber, whatsapp, and iOS message app too.

I just want to group up my 20 push messages to one message on lock screen.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some code so users could understand your problem & help you to resolve it.

Comment: I have never seen such behavior

Comment: my push is already working. but i want some thing like viber settings.In viber app if you goes to settings -> Notification-> then you will see a switch with option "show preview". if you switch this off then all your viber push messages group up into one message. that thing i want. thanks